# MySQL creates another PRIMARY KEY

Tags: php, mysql

I try to create a simplest table for article material, but MySQL creates for me another primary key I don't need.

```
$command = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$this->table` (
            `id` int unsigned UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            `title` varchar(200),
            `body` text,
            `author` varchar(100),
            `last_moderator` varchar(100),
            `category` int(10),
            `cdate` datetime,
            `lmdate` datetime,
            `commentable` boolean,
            `active` boolean ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
                ";
```

Here's the query. As you can see I need id to be a primary key, but this query results in two primary keys: `id` and `body`. People help me please - I meditate on this query for 20 minutes, but I don't see any mistakes.

Comment: Is it a primary key on body or just an index? I checked your query, it creates the pk on id only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

er, no it doesn't.... `body` isn't defined as a key, primary or otherwise:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTable` (
    ->             `id` int unsigned UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->             `title` varchar(200),
    ->             `body` text,
    ->             `author` varchar(100),
    ->             `last_moderator` varchar(100),
    ->             `category` int(10),
    ->             `cdate` datetime,
    ->             `lmdate` datetime,
    ->             `commentable` boolean,
    ->             `active` boolean ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> show indexes from myTable;
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| myTable |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| myTable |          0 | id       |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: http://i58.fastpic.ru/big/2015/0415/e9/01f13c9d79dad180759d54f42b5594e9.png
Maybe hosting provider 'makes' my brain?

Comment: You might have something that creates an extra key on `body`, but it isn't that command; and it can't be a second primary key because MySQL only permits  a single primary key per table

Comment: Mark, I know, but my eyes tell me absoulutely different thing. Actully that's why I am here

Comment: Drop the table, then execute that command you've posted, and only that command with nothing else that could conceivable affect the database in any way..... because neither PHP nor MySQL is known for arbitrarily creating additional primary keys on arbitrary columns

Comment: Already done many times with different corrections and without them. I executed the query from MyAdmin and as a PHP code and nothing except this function creates tables. I have no ideas what it is

Comment: Do a `show indexes from <tablename>` from MySQL itself.... it's always possible that phpmyadmin is misinterpreting things

Comment: `show indexes` shows that `id` is the  only primary key. I hope it will work properly

Comment: This is why I don't use GUI front end tools like phpmyadmin when I'm working with a  database